# Special Characters move to beginning of line in the_content

Tags: php, wordpress, special-characters

I have a wordpress site http://perfectskinsolutions.co.uk/test/ and all text is formatting fine except the blog posts text in the_content.

Any special characters move to the beginning of the line. This doesn't happen in the archive pages, or the_excerpt just when displaying the_content. The characters are fine, just at the beginning of the line so -

Test!

changes to -

!Test

Can anyone shed some light please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just go to your stylesheet "style.css" and go to line number 12:

```
.rev{
     /*direction: rtl;*/       comment this line
     text-align: left;
     }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just adding content so was not aware that was in there, or even that it could do that!